# Patches with vs2010 and install shield LE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, patch, installshield-le

I have a TFS setup with visual studio 2010 and install shield LE. I was wondering if anyone can answer me this question (sorry if its just plain ignorance)

When I queue a build with tfs all goes well. The installer is created as part of my project and all is merry. I want to know if there is a way to release a patch via this type of setup. So if i change code in various projects in the solution, and I want to have an installer built that will just apply said changes in the form of a patch, what would i need to do? Just to be clear, I can queue a new build. Remove the existing application on a machine and install the new build with the changes, I am just wondering if there is an easier/better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to create an MSI-patch as part of your setup? Ie. you run the build for the second time and it creates a patch installer with regards to the first build?

This is not so easy as it sounds. To be able to create an MSI patch, you need both MSI's for a full setup to be able to determine the delta between the two versions.

For more information about MSI patching, [see here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370578%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)